# Why can't Bolzano-Weierstrass be proved by choosing peak element and then iteratively peak of sequence after last peak?

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-explanation

In coursebook's proof: Let $(x_n)$ be limited sequence.

Then first is created subsequence $$a_k = sup\lbrace x_n:n\geq k\rbrace$$

So we are choosing first supremum of whole sequence, and then supremum of sequence which is whole sequence minus sequence up to point of latest supremum, et cetera.

At this point sequence $a_k$ is limited and decreasing, thus it is convergent and when $k\rightarrow \infty$ we have $\lim(a_k) = \inf (a_k) \equiv a$

Then from here it's worked out to from, where theorem is proved by principle I couldn't find english translation for, and which I think is irrelevant.

But for the actual question, why can't I, instead of supremums of the parts, choose the actual peaks? So that sequence $a_k$ would consist only elements of original sequence, and giving convergent subsequence right away.

Comment: I could just be ignorant on the topic but I have never heard the word embryo used in a mathematical context. Embryo, refers to
"an unborn or unhatched offspring in the process of development."

Comment: Not quite sure if this answers your question, but if by peak you mean "an element of the sequence greater than every subsequent element," i.e call $a_k$ a peak if $a_k \geq a_j$ for all $j \geq k$, well then what if you have only finitely many peaks? You don't have enough to generate a full subsequence.

Comment: @Quality Sorry, that and "germ" were only translations google offered, fixed it now.

Comment: I think the problem is simply that you possibly don't have peaks: what if the supremum is not a maximum? For example, in an asymptotically increasing sequence. Like $0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{8},...$

Comment: Already said,....but: For $x_n=(n-1)/n$ every $a_k=1$.

Comment: @mb- Thanks, hadn't faced anywere that finite sequence cannot be called convergent, though maybe it can be worked from definition of limit.

Comment: @57Jimmy But in that case, weird that book's proof simply assumes that $a_k$ froms a convergent sequence, when there can possibly be finite amount (or only 1) of $a_k$, or am I still missing something which would make it an infinite sequence?

Comment: @PyHop The point is: you need a rule that to every $k$ assigns some value, in order to define a sequence. In the book, $a_k$ is always defined, even if it is constant. But if you just say "as next element take the next peak", this is not well-defined, in the case that there is no next peak.